# double click from Grid Panel and pass value to text field in new window EXT 3.3.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, extjs, ext.net, gridpanel

***SOLVED***

I have a function:

```
function MethodA_OpenWindow(Title, Id, Height, Width, Url) {}
```

In aspx:

```
 <Listeners>                       
     <RowDblClick Handler="MethodA_OpenWindow('Test Form','Window',600,1000,'testform.aspx');"></RowDblClick>    
 </Listeners>
```

'RowDblClick Handler' is able to open to a new window and hence how can i pass the selected row value from Grid Panel to new window text field?

Thank You.
[*refer picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWJH.jpg)